# According to universal-image-loader URL how to get the path stored in the local picture

Tags: android

> According to universal-image-loader URL how to get the path stored in
>   the local picture

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problems

I haven't found any of the following image loaders expose access to the underlying file "Cache";

Universal Image Loader

Volley Image Loader

Picasso

Volley, remains possible, by skipping the ImageLoader, and querying the same queue with a regular Request with the same URL. Volley will recognise the request for the file and deliver the data (in memory), from there you can save it off to somewhere more convenient like external storage.

I believe the RoboSpice also allows access to the underlying data, but I find it's lazy loading implementation completely inadequate in general.